# SQLite query to get email addresses from AirMail app

Tags: sqlite, email, email-address

I'm trying to get the email addresses from the AirMail Mac application (from http://airmailapp.com). The email addresses are stored in a binary BLOB in a SQLite database.
Has anyone written any code in any language to extract email addresses?
Thanks in advance,
SRG

Comment: Is the format of the email addresses documented, and if so, what is it?  If you don't know what it is, then the first step might be to open a sample database using the SQLite3 command line tool and examine the contents of the e-mail BLOB, and see if you can deduce the structure.

Comment: have you examined a sample db, and saved the blob to a file to see what that field with the email addresses looks like?  You can do something like: `SELECT writefile('emailfile.txt', emailColumn) from t1 limit 1;`

Comment: I've opened up my own database and have done some inspection.  Being a binary field, it's less than fun to play with.  There are some consistencies I can work with such as the email address starting on line 4 position 20 and continuing until it is terminated with a specific character. I can certainly work from there but if someone had already parsed that field, it would save a lot of effort.
Thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: I'm somewhat confused about your description, specifically about the email address beginning on "line 4 position 20" - normally one would not expect BLOBs to have lines.  I gather the email address itself is in ASCII and so is recognizable?

Comment: Good questions.  I should have been more clear.  Yes, it is a binary large object field. There is a lot of information stored in there, including stuff in non-ASCII format for some reason.  There are embedded CRLF characters, thus I could count 4 CRLFs, plus 20 additional characters and the email address starts there in plain ASCII. Performance isn't all that important to me as this will be a one-off data extraction.

Comment: I suspect that it will be easier extracting the e-mail address from the BLOB it is embedded in by using your application language rather than using SQLite itself to break apart the BLOB.  If you *do* want to explore an SQLite-only solution, then you should look at the SQLite functions instr() and substr(), but I expect this will be the hard way.